# Delete Query not working (No bugs/syntax errors)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

```
<input type="hidden" name="code"
        value="<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Delete">

// Get ID
$code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'productCode', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

// Delete the product from the database
if ($code != false) {
    $query = 'DELETE FROM products
              WHERE productCode = :productCode';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':productCode', $code);
    $success = $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}
```

The code at the top is trying to get the code into where the php/MySQL code at the bottom of the screen here. There's no bugs that fly or trigger when the code runs in the webpage, and the code doesn't flag anything in the editor. I'm really at a loss for what's going wrong here, and no one that I ask has any idea what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think it might be an idea to reinitialise $code

Answer (score 2):

table field is `prdocutcode` why are you only name is code replace below  my code

```
 <input type="hidden" name="productCode" value="<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you log out the :productCode? It's possible that the value is not what you think, and a delete for a non-existent item will happily report nothing if no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have HTML and PHP codes in the same file.

What might be the issue:

Add condition if the form is posted, go for deleting product.

```
if (isset($_POST['productCode'])) {
 // Get ID
 $code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'productCode', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
 // Delete the product from the database
 if ($code != false) {
    $query = 'DELETE FROM products
              WHERE productCode = :productCode';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':productCode', $code);
    $success = $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are posting value with different key and getting it with different, and I believe this can be the reason, replace your hidden input with following

```
<input type="hidden" name="productCode" value="<?php echo $product['productCode']; ?>">
```

Also you need to take care about php tags `<?php ?>`, which should start and end for php script.

Answer (score 0):

Please use AJAX post request for delete by code.